# Приложение выдает ошибку на старой версии Android

Tags: java, android, button

Мое приложение на андроид 6.0.1 работает без нареканий, а когда попробовал поставить на 4.4.2 и на 4.4.4 - оба раза выдавало эту ошибку.

Попробовал удалить задний фон кнопки, и все сработало. Суть в том, что задний фон есть везде в приложении, фон ставлю через drawable папку вот так: `android:background="@drawable/rectangle_bluedark"`.

**xml**:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle" >

<corners
    android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="10dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
    android:topRightRadius="10dp" />

<stroke
    android:width="1dp"
    android:color="@android:color/darker_gray" />

<solid android:color="@color/napravleniyakapuyt2" /> </shape>
```

**ошибка**:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main   Process: ********, PID: 19216   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{**************}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #120: Error inflating class Button
      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2338)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
   Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #120: Error inflating class Button
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:292)
      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
      at *******.onCreate(******.java:39)
      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5264)
      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2302)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321) 
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640) 
      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
   Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f0200a6 a=-1 r=0x7f0200a6}
      at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2124)
      at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
      at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3579)
      at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:642)
      at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:107)
      at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton.<init>(AppCompatButton.java:66)
      at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton.<init>(AppCompatButton.java:62)
      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:109)
      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1029)
      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1087)
      at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:47)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:684)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755) 
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758) 
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758) 
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758) 
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:292) 
      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
      at ******.onCreate(**********.java:39) 
      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5264) 
      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2302) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321) 
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640) 
      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чём проблема?

Comment: Покажи свой color "@color/napravleniyakapuyt2"

Comment: @A-Z вот <color name="napravleniyakapuyt2">#004a91</color>

Comment: разметку здесь укажите экрана и укажите 120 строку в ней

Comment: еще есть смутное предположение, что дело в @android:color/darker_gray - замените хардкодом или ссылкой на ваш ресурс

Comment: @Chaynik я все попробовал ни чего не помогает, но когда удаляю backround все работает , может быть чтото связанно с памятью ?

Comment: ну у вас как минимум отсуствует нужный участок кода в вопросе

Comment: Судя по логам он не может xml во вьюху распарсить и конкретно указывает на 120 строку разметки, проблему нужно искать именно в ней. У меня был случай что на одном леново drawable из xml не создавался и всё крэшилось, а на остальных девайсах всё нормально.

Comment: @Chaynik что добавить ?